# how do i convert photographs to tensors

Tags: converters, photos, tensorflow

I am a neophyte neural network user trying to get to grips with TensorFlow. I have used the MNIST dataset as a test, and would now like to use real world data.
Can anyone point me to a "Howto" or paper or source which tells me how to go about converting digital photographs in files, (jpeg, png, gif, wmf), into a tensors ready for import into TensorFlow please?

Cheers!

Comment: https://github.com/HamedMP/ImageFlow has some nice code for converting images into TFRecords. This could help. If you instead want to operate with bytes, then you need some code similar to the the CIFAR10 example in TF. What's your specific use case?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer; I will download ImageFlow and give it a go. The use case is identification of bumblebees.

Comment: I have located and downloaded the ImageFlow module, but the documentation is not clear when using the command: convert_images(images, labels, filename). Can anyone please show me an example of how to use this command please? (For example it asks for a label for each image - can that be right?)

Comment: @AndrewLewis you don't need to download it, you can just install it into your environment via `pip instal imageflow`. About the lack of documentation I will fix that, but to answer you question now, you read images into a bumpy array using PIL/Pillow, let say images shape is [1000,32, 32, 3] and also read labels corresponding to these images in a 1-D array indication the class of the images, the array looks like [1000] and each element is from 0 to num_class-1. Hope this helps. If not let me know, you can also open a github issue, so I can respond faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TensorFlow image functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image) to load images and convert them into tensors. After loading the images, you will likely want to look at [`tf.image.resize_bilinear`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_bilinear) to resize the images to standard sizes.

Comment: That first link is broken

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to load data into Tensorflow is to use a TFRecords file.

> Another approach is to convert whatever data you have into a supported format. This approach makes it easier to mix and match data sets and network architectures. The recommended format for TensorFlow is a TFRecords file containing tf.train.Example protocol buffers.

-[Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data)

Basically TFRecord is a binary representation of your data or images along with its labels, file names, and other information. Its main advantages are to allow you to stream data into the model efficiently by using Tensorflow's threading and to increase flexibility between different models.

You can use this [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py) to generate your own TFRecord files.

Additionally, you can read on how to use the script [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-construct-a-new-dataset-for-retraining).

Comment: The script moved to here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py